# Deserializing multiple objects from asynchronous socket

Tags: sockets, object, asynchronous, deserialization

All,

I'm a bit of a newbie to C# and socket programming and I would need some advice. I have been looking on this site and similar sites but haven't really found a solution for my problem.

I am developing a client application and a server application and the two are communicating over an asynchronous socket. The client sends objects to the server, one at a time, by serializing it to a MemoryStream using BinaryFormatter. The resulting byte array is sent over the socket and deserialized by the server.

This works well when the server has time to receive and process the object before the client sends a new one. However when the client sends objects faster than the server can handle them, they queue up at the server side. The next EndReceive() call reads all queued objects from the socket, but the serializer only deserializes the first object and the other ones are lost.

The objects are of variable size, so I guess I can't use the Position property of MemoryStream. Is there a way to detect in the byte array where objects start ?

Also, I have read in other posts that EndReceive() may not receive everything that has been sent in one read, other reads may be needed. So I guess that's something else I'll have to deal with ?

Any pointers ? Any help would be greatly appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could read as much as is availble and "queue" it up for processing so that the socket isn't queued up.  You could have the server receiving the data simply reading and sending the data into a message queue for processing asynchronously.

It's concerning that the server can't process fast enough to keep up with writes though; you might want to look into optimizing that.

Comment: Thanks for replying.. My main problem is how to deserialize multiple objects. When the server receives a byte array that contains say 2 objects, how to deserialize the second one ? I guess I'll have to use the Position property of the MemoryStream class, but I don't know the size of the objects. Is there a way of finding out the size of the objects from the contents of the byte array ?